# Backbone Router is not working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've been trying for 2 whole days now. I went through crossroads, pathjs, davis, and 10000 other libraries, all of which either required ton of dependencies or were very intrusive. All I need is a simple PURELY HTML5 Router that is not 200kb. I don't care for IE6, or IE8 for that matter.

My latest try was the one integrated into backbone.

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend ({
    initialize: function()
    {
        console.log(this);
    },

    routes: {
        '/' : 'home',
        '': 'home',
        'work': 'home',
        '/work': 'home'
    },
    home: function () {
        alert('Backbone sux');
    }
});

var appRouter = new Router(); 
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
```

Isn't that supposed to cut it? Am I not supposed to simply write

```
<a href = "/work"></a>  <a href ="/"></a>
```

And see my beautiful alert message?

Comment: Try visiting `<a href = "#work"></a>` instead of `/work`

Comment: I don't want hashes. That's what 'pushState: true' is suppoused to do, acoording to the documentation.

Comment: This may be of some help: http://artsy.github.io/blog/2012/06/25/replacing-hashbang-routes-with-pushstate/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As alluded to by cclerville, Backbone does NOT automatically match URLs like you are trying to do. You have to add a little more script to get that working. I use the following.

```
// All navigation that is relative should be passed through the navigate
// method, to be processed by the router. If the link has a `data-bypass`
// attribute, bypass the delegation completely.
//
// @link https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone-boilerplate/blob/master/app/main.js
$(document).on('click', 'a[href]:not([data-bypass])', function(event) {
    var href = $(this).prop('href'),
        root = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + module.config().rootUrl + '/';

    if (href.slice(0, root.length) === root) {
        event.preventDefault();

        Backbone.history.navigate(href.slice(root.length), true);
    }
});
```